# How to show 5 top data when using subscribe in nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, nativescript

From this function I get all my data from ws.

```
 public data: Data[];
    getall() {
        this.ws.getalldata().subscribe(
            data=> {
                this.data= data;
            }
        );
    }
```

Json file:

```
 {
        "StatusCode": 0,
        "StatusMessage": "OK",
        "StatusDescription": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "id_type": 1,
                "desc": "TRTY",
                "active": 0,
                },
              ....
             {
                "id": "3",
                "id_type": 50,
                "desc": "qqq",
                "active": 0,
            },
            {
                "id": "4",
                "id_type": 50,
                "desc": "qqq",
                "active": 0,
            },
               ......
           {
                "id": "30",
                "id_type": 2,
                "desc": "hhh",
                "active": 0,
            }
          }
```

I can show those data in html like when use this code:

```
  <StackLayout *ngFor="let item of data">                
        <Label row="1" col="1" text="" class="list-group-item-text" [text]='item.id_type'></Label>
        <Label row="1" col="1" text="" class="list-group-item-text" [text]='item.desc'></Label>
     </StackLayout>
```

My question is, how to show only 5 top data in template? I want to show only 5 top element, not all.

Comment: The first 5 or the first 5 based on a criteria?

Comment: you could apply a filter to the array according to which 5 you wish to have

Comment: Please, can you write something? @mast3rd3mon

Comment: it depends which 5 you are after, the first 5? the last 5? 5 with active not 0?

Comment: @Ploppy, I want to display only 5 new elements added to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Following RxJs documentation](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/take), if you want to work with the 5 last items, you should do something like this (RxJs 6):

```
import { concatAll, takeLast } from 'rxjs/operators';

public data: Data[] = [];
...

    this.ws.getalldata().pipe(concatAll(), takeLast(5)).subscribe(
        item=> {
            this.data.push(item);
        }
    );
```

Another solution is to work on the array itself,

```
    this.ws.getalldata().subscribe(
        data=> {
            this.data = data.slice(-5)
        }
    );
```

Comment: 2 Solution show 5 elements that have been added to the beginning, I want to display 5 elements that have been added to the last list. Thnx for answer

Comment: @Anolua your question was not clear about that. I edited my answer for you, do not hesitate to edit your question to specify *5 last elements of the list*.